# Can I give access to database without access to cpanel

Tags: cpanel, database, freelancer

I'm going to give a freelancer access to the database. The idea was to give him the access with SSH (MySQL Workbench). But it came out that to do so, I would need to give him the password to my cpanel as well. Is there any other way, to give a database access without giving the access to the cpanel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a user for them in cpanel and then provide them with the login and password. There's no need for them to have access to cpanel to access the database.